# Search a binary file for a list of 500 000 binary patterns

Tags: command-line, grep, search, binary

I have a list of binary "strings" in a file delimited by newlines. I'd like to use that to search another binary file to check which of these patterns the binary files contains and at which offset. I'd want to use a CLI command instead of a GUI application. The patterns file is about 200M in size.

I've tried using the following, however, grep gets terminated after a couple of seconds:

```
grep -f patternsFile -aF targetBinary
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How did you even generate the files with the "strings"? The problem is that in a context of "binary", newline is meaningless. New line only have meaning in text. In binary it's just another "byte".  And `grep` is meant to handle text and not binary, so that's probably the wrong approach. Do you even know if any of the "binary strings" in your set actually appear in the file?